# Composer is not loading my locally installed package

Tags: docker, composer-php

I've installed [this](https://github.com/JorgeAnzola/environment-protection) (environment-protection) Craft plugin locally, in the vendor folder it appears symlinked, but when I try loading the project in the browser, it gives me:

**include(/var/www/vendor/composer/../jorgeanzola/environment-protection/src/EnvironmentProtection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

I've tried running composer dump and restarting Docker several times. I'm missing something.

This is my composer.json

```
{
  "name": "jorgeanzola/craft-boilerplate",
  "description": "Boilerplate with Craft, webpack and Docker.",
  "type": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "keywords": [
    "craft",
    "cms",
    "craftcms",
    "craft-plugin",
    "environment protection"
  ],
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "plugins/craft-recipe",
      "options": {
        "symlink": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "plugins/environment-protection",
      "options": {
        "symlink": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "aelvan/imager": "v2.1.10",
    "clubstudioltd/craft-asset-rev": "^6.0",
    "craftcms/cms": "^3.0.0",
    "craftcms/redactor": "2.3.3.2",
    "ether/seo": "^3.5",
    "jorgeanzola/environment-protection": "@dev",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  }
}
```

## update #1

So, I think the problem is not composer but docker not ready the symlink.

Comment: Maybe you need to provide dockerfile, minimal php code to let folks to reproduce. Symlink suppose work in container, or you may use it something special which you did not realize to put it in the post...

Comment: Is the folder the symlink points to part of your docker image and if so, can you check if it was correctly symlinked inside your container? If it really is a docker problem, more details on how you set it up would indeed be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was just a dumb mistake on my side: I have the folders in my computer something like this:

---| ~/Components

---|---| ~/Components/plugins

---|---| ~/Components/craft (installation to test the plugins)

---|---|---|  ~/Components/craft/plugins (I forgot it was **symlinked** from the folder *~/Components/plugins/*

So I was trying to install locally plugins that were symlinked from a folder outside the container.